# Drupal 7 - privatemsg module - autocomplete customisation

Tags: drupal, private-messaging

I have a privatemsg module in Drupal 7, which uses autocomplete in field "To" (Do is polish translation). It looks very unattractive and I see no option to customise it unfortunately! I checked the code and I tried to modify it, but it doesn't work :o

```
<input type="text" id="edit-recipient" name="recipient" value="" size="50" maxlength="128" class="form-text required form-autocomplete" />

<input type="hidden" id="edit-recipient-autocomplete" value="http://niemiecki.dogadajsie.pl/messages/autocomplete" disabled="disabled" class="autocomplete" />
```

As we can see the autocomplete has id="edit-recipient-autocomplete" and class="autocomplete". When I modify it, it just doesn't work in any way. When I tried to search for reference to this id or class I found nothing. Can somebody tell me how to customise it?

Actually it looks like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/r6Gej.png

Kind regards, Michael.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to modify with the field? You can use hook_form_alter to modify the field. The auto complete class is added because its explicitly set for auto complete.

Comment: I want to add margin-top:3px, change border and add background-color there where it is transparent, but I cannot style it..

Comment: In hook_form_alter, add `#attributes => array('style' => 'margine-top:3px');` for that particular field